# My object javascript is not fully sent to the back

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to send an object from front to back.

this is my function :

```
export const addComponent = (newComponent, inputFields) => (dispatch) => {
    const url = process.env.REACT_APP_ADD_COMPONENT;
    var componentBody = {
        type: newComponent.type,
        name: newComponent.name,
    };

    var componentTest = inputFields.map((inputField) => {
        return Object.defineProperty(componentBody, inputField.property, {
            value: inputField.content,
        });
    });

    console.log(componentTest);
    axios
        .put(url, componentTest)
        .then(dispatch({ type: ADD_COMPONENT, payload: componentTest }))
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Add failed", err);
        });
};
```

When I log componentTest, it get the strucutre that I want, which mean :

```
{
description: "je décris",
environnement: "j'environne",
name: "test",
type: "Données"
}
```

But  on the backside, in my route when I log req.body, there is only type and name which are present. Like if the defineProperty function doesn't records my object...

I presume that i need to enumerate all the properties of my object, but my knowledges stop here

Comment: Your `type: "Données` is an  unterminated string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded it,

If someone else need it.

With `defineProperty` you need to configure your new object by adding :

```
    var componentTest = inputFields.map((inputField) => {
        return Object.defineProperty(componentBody, inputField.property, {
            value: inputField.content,
            writable: true,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
        });
    });
```

Now i can see my object fully.